# Outputting a snippet of arbitrary HTML document content without open tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, substring

For example, a snippet of 50 characters.  Problem is, of course, closing any opened tags.  What's a good way to do this?  Or else to make things easier, what's a good way to completely skim off all HTML content from the snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tags are generally allowed in the text (I mean, if, for example, text contains <b>, text must be marked with **bold**, etc), then looks like [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function is the easiest variant to remove tags from snippet.

If tags are generally not allowed in the text (for example, "<b>" must be just displayed as "<b>"), then you can use [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

Comment: Didn't know about htmlentities.  Is that the reverse of htmlspecialchars?

Comment: htmlspecialchars() replaces only ampersand, quotes, less-than and greater-than symbols. htmlentities() replaces ALL characters, which have any equivalent representation in HTML. html_entity_decode() decodes back result of htmlentities().

Answer (score 5):

You can strip out all HTML tags, etc. via the [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) function, which is (being realistic) probably the best way to go, as otherwise you'll most likely end up with more tags than actual content.

For example:

```
$first50Chars = substr(trim(strip_tags($longString)), 0, 50);
```